# Javascript How can I reload only once?

Tags: javascript

How can I make the my code reload only once? The code is set to reload every 5 seconds is a javascript code. Here is the code:

---

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#ReloadPage").load(location.href+" #ReloadPage>*","");
}, 500); // seconds to wait, miliseconds
```

---

How can I make my code reload only once?

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve? To load the sub-page twice but not after that? Why every 5 seconds? (And an interval of 500 is 0.5 seconds, not 5 seconds).

Answer (score 3):

How about using a hash like this:-

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#ReloadPage").load(location.href+" #ReloadPage>*","");
}, 500); // seconds to wait, miliseconds
```

Comment: That did not do it actually are you sure?

Comment: how is this different from the OP's question??

Comment: yes very sure it will do it once, if you are not calling the function contains this code recursively

Comment: @GeniaS. The difference is that it uses `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: Ah yes... sorry... was never very good at those "what's different here" games.

Comment: but you should also point out that 500 is half a second, not 5 seconds.

Comment: @GeniaS. yes you are right, 500 is half a second it should be 5000